# How to have searchable dropdown in Redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-select

I'm using field-arrays from redux-form and i need a searchable dropdown menu in my form. I know a normal dropdown could be done like this,

```
<Field name={`${object}.method`} component="select" validate={required} id={`${object}.key`}>
       <option value="id">id</option>
       <option value="css">css</option>
       <option value="xpath">xpath</option>
       <option value="binding">binding</option>
       <option value="model">model</option>
</Field>
```

But this is not searchable dropwdownlist. Even if i were to use this, this is only giving a basic html select, how would i be able to apply css style to this to make it match other bootstrap elements?

To have a searchable dropdownlist, I'm using [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) package. What I tried to do was;

```
<Field
    name={`${object}.method`}
    type='text'
    component={this.renderDropdown}
    label="Method"
    validate={required}
    id={`${object}.key`}
    valueField='value'
/>

renderDropdown = ({ input, id, valueField, meta: { touched, error }, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className='align-inline object-field-length'>
                <Select {...input} id={id} value={input.value.value} onChange={input.onChange}
                    options={[
                        { value: 'id', label: 'id' },
                        { value: 'css', label: 'css' },
                        { value: 'xpath', label: 'xpath' },
                        { value: 'binding', label: 'binding' },
                        { value: 'model', label: 'model' },
                    ]}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
```

This is not working correctly, **the value is getting stored in the redux-store only when the dropdown is active**(when it is being clicked), on event blur this loses the value.

What am i doing wrong here?

**Is it possible to have searchable dropdownlist in redux-form?**

Comment: You can check below example
https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Comment: I suggest you to use `autocomplete` dropdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question, finally i figured i couldn't use react-select package with redux-form.

When the value is being selected it gets added to the react-store but loses the value on event blur. This happens because the redux-form onBlur event triggers an action, which passes null in its payload. To avoid this there are a couple of solutions mentioned in the [github issue thread](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2768)

By defining a custom method to handle onBlur did it for me;

```
renderDropdown = ({ input, onBlur, id, meta: { touched, error }, ...props }) => {

 const handleBlur = e => e.preventDefault();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Select {...input}
                id="object__dropdown--width"
                options={allRepos}
                onChange={input.onChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur} 
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}



  <Field name="listAllRepo" 
      value="this.state.accountno" 
      component={this.renderDropdown} 
      placeholder="Select" 
  />
```

Hope this would be helpful for someone else!

Comment: If only i would have found this question 4 days ago. thanks iit girl.

Answer (score 0):

There is react-select package for react which give searchable feature

```js
<Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
        searchable={true}
      />
```

follow at [github](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am already using react-select package. My question is how to use react-select in redux-form.

Comment: In redux form can dispatch action like change, submit etc. While onChange you have to fire action on change with data to the associated from.

Comment: Yes, im aware of that. But im not sure how to update the state in a redux-form using fieldarrays. Since im not directly interacting with the state, so far the fieldarray is popping and adding items to the state. At least thats my understanding so far